# getting the full name of an assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Suppose I want to display the full name of an assembly, given only a path to the assembly file.

I know I could write a command line program or powershell script easily enough, but does the runtime include a command that I could use? (I've seen gacutil do it for assemblies that are in the gac, but about assemblies that are not registered?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main *problematic* part of a full-name is usually the public key token. You can obtain it by entering this into the Visual Studio Command Prompt Window:

```
sn -T path\to\your.dll
```

Personally, I find it easier just to load the dll into reflector, though. That shows the full name in the bottom panel.

Comment: Instead of loading it into reflector, you could just write a console app :D

Comment: @Marc close enough -- I would use reflector or even just [System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionLoadFrom().FullName in Powershell, but I need an easy cmd line util that I can pass to a support person -- just rolled my own.

Answer (score 17):

I think you're looking for System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName:

```
AssemblyName name = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\path\assembly.dll");
Console.WriteLine(name.FullName);
```

Unlike the solution using Assembly.Load, this will not load the assembly into your AppDomain. This will allow you to get the AssemblyName for an assembly without having to resolve any references that assembly has, and without executing any code (e.g. module static constructors) in the assembly. It will even let you get the AssemblyName of an assembly that targets a version of the .NET Framework that differs from the version on which your application is running.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I'm looking for.  I do know how to do it in code.  What I was after was a command line option, becuase I have to teach a support person how to do this.  I was hoping that there was a built-in cmd that would get me what I wanted -- ended up rolling my own.

Comment: Might not have been what JMarsch was looking for, but was exactly what I wanted myself! Thanks

Comment: Very useful in combination with `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(...)`

Answer (score 4):

You can get this via [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx):

```
var name = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);
var fullname = name.FullName;
```

This avoids actually loading the assembly into your process.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I'm looking for. I do know how to do it in code. What I was after was a command line option, becuase I have to teach a support person how to do this. I was hoping that there was a built-in cmd that would get me what I wanted -- ended up rolling my own.  HOWEVER -- I was using Assembly.ReflectionLoadFrom().  I'll switch over to use AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName +1 for the AssemblyName tip anyways.

Answer (score 4):

For another answer, you can do this with PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($PathToAssembly).FullName
```

This has the advantage of not needing to have Visual Studio installed just to get `sn.exe`, and also that it returns the complete strong name for the assembly rather than just the public key token.

It's easy enough to wrap that in a cmdlet script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    $Path
)

Process {
    $FullPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($Path);
    return [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($FullPath).FullName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I'm looking for. I do know how to do it in code. What I was after was a command line option, becuase I have to teach a support person how to do this. I was hoping that there was a built-in cmd that would get me what I wanted -- ended up rolling my own